Transistor won't fully turn off when Fan PWM is connected
I'm trying to use a RP2040-zero to control a 12V PC fan that also has a PWM and tach connection. I'm using a transistor to turn off the fan completely as a 0% duty cycle on PWM doesn't turn the fan off, it only spins it down to a really slow speed.
When I use the GPIO pin to turn on the transistor, everything seems to be working. The fan spins as expected, I'm able to control the speed with PWM, and I can read the signals from the tach to get the rpm. When I drive the GPIO pin that is connected to the transistor base low, the fan spins down and stops. But the problem is that the fan is making a clicking sound starting right before it stops and then the whole time when it is stopped.
I measured the voltage between the collector and +12V when the GPIO pin is high and I see right around 12V as expected. But when the GPIO pin is low, the voltage drops to 8V, it doesn't drop to zero. I also tried tying the base directly to ground just to rule out any GPIO issues and also see 8V.
The interesting part is that if I disconnect the PWM connection to the fan, everything starts working properly. I see the collector at 12V and 0V when the GPIO pin is high and low. So somehow the PWM connection is interfering with being able to turn off the transistor.
I tried looking for another question here that had the same problem as me but couldn't find one. I'm assuming this is probably something stupid that I'm missing due to a lack of experience. Here is the schematic for the circuit:


The 12V Power supply's ground is not common to the logical one in your schematics. Is that a mistake ?

The LM2596 is not an isolated converter so the grounds should be harmonized if the built circuit reflects its schematic.

@MathieuG. The ground is common across the whole circuit. This is the way Fritzing did the connections.

Switching the fan on the low side is a mistake here; when the transistor is off there will be a current path through the fan and the tach/PWM pins.  You could use the NPN transistor to pull down the base of a PNP between the 12V supply and the fan.  Also, the 68R is rather low as a base resistor; the GPIO pins will only be good for a few mA so they will limit the current, which explains why you’re seeing 8V rather than zero.  If you’re adding a second transistor then consider about 10k there and maybe 1k to limit base current for the PNP to around 10mA which will be ok for a fan current of a few hundred mA.  Use less than 1k if you need to to get the PNP to switch on fully.

Thank you @Frog, using the NPN transistor to switch the PNP transistor between the 12V and the fan solved my problem and everything is working perfectly now.
